# Using an html "data-" attribute

Tags: javascript, html

Consider a line such as this:

```
<div id='abc' onclick='DoSomething(this.id)'></div>
```

Now, suppose it's expanded to be something more like this:

```
<div id='abc' data-something='whatever' onclick='DoSomething(this.id)'></div>
```

There's no functional difference here yet, but this is my question.  I'm looking for a way to pass the value of 'data-something' to the DoSomething function instead of the id.  I can't seem to find a method of doing this? Is it possible?

Something like the following would be nice, but of course it's not how it works. (I'm only including it to help illustrate the intended goal.

```
<div id='abc' data-something='whatever' onclick='DoSomething(this.data-something)'></div>
```

Comment: And you copied and pasted the same error over and over. Missing a `'`

Comment: Read this: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: As a combination of the answers, you could make a function that takes advantage of `dataset` and falls back to `getAttribute`: http://jsfiddle.net/C3rnr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to do `this.getAttribute("data-something")`, like so:

```
<div id='abc' data-something='whatever' onclick='DoSomething(this.getAttribute("data-something"))></div>
```

or you can use `this.dataset.something`.

[Here is my source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml)

Comment: This solution will work for our application perfectly. Thanks much! As a side note, we can't use the id for our purpose because we are integrating code that comes from two different sources with some (currently unfinished) in-house automation tools.  The id's are unpredictable and uncontrollable from our side, so we have to rely on these extra data attributes (which are predictable and known to us) to accomplish our goal.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 10):

You can do

```
DoSomething(this.dataset.something)
```

But it's generally recommended to separate the javascript part and the HTML, which is especially easy when your element has an id :

```
<div id='abc' data-something='whatever'></div>
<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').onclick = function(){
        DoSomething(this.dataset.something)
    }
</script>
```

On Internet Explorer, [support for dataset is incomplete](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset). On IE10-, You need to use

```
DoSomething(this.getAttribute('data-something'))
```

Comment: Just make sure it is available in the browsers you need to support [can I use dataset](http://caniuse.com/dataset)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getAttribute` method:

```
<div id='abc' data-something='whatever' onclick='DoSomething(this.getAttribute("data-something")'></div>
```

But I highly suggest that you aviod inline javascript delegation to elements. You should better use DOM or jQuery for that and note that **jQuery** has a method for easier **data-*** attributes handling.

Answer (score 0):

if you want consider jQuery you could convert your code in somethings like that:

**html**

```
<div id="abc" data-something="whatever">click here</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#abc').on('click', function () {
        DoSomething($(this).attr('data-something'));
    });
});
```

or better

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#abc').on('click', function () {
        DoSomething($(this));
    });
});

function DoSomething(obj){
    alert(obj.attr('id'));
    alert(obj.attr('data-something'));
}
```